# In iDraw 2.5 how do you tag layers or objects

Tags: idraw

There is nothing in the user guide about tagging things, and I'm trying to export some graphics to Xcode.

Comment: What does tagging accomplish?

Comment: When exporting it says tagged layers and objects, and i just want the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Have you tried "export" instead of "export layers" in the menu "file"?

[image: export objects]

> **2015 iDraw Guide here:**
>
> http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/downloads/iDrawUserGuide.pdf

---

## Hide layers?

Maybe try hiding the layers you don't want before exporting, and leave the box "include hidden layers" unchecked.

[image: Tag objects iDraw]

**Add the objects' extension**

[image: Tag object with extensions]

**Go in "File" menu and select "Export layers"**

[image: Tag at export]

**Should get you this:**

[image: Final objects in folder iDraw]

> Source:
> https://youtu.be/y_-8XknW86U?t=42s and http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/new/

---

Comment: Hmmm maybe sounds like a plan I will try it.

Comment: No, it didn't work, yes it only export the visible layers but export them complete and I want it object by object separate in the second suggestion, the first just exports the whole canvas with everything in it as one file.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso Did you add the extensions to the objects as in the second screenshot of the second option? I don't use iDraw but it seems to only export objects when you do that.

Comment: What extenstion? .png??

Comment: Well apparently it was adding .png to the shapes now I need to find out why some are going empty, thanks.